for transformers import AutoImageProcessor, AutoModel: ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes for transformers import
When trying to use the AutoImageProcessor and the AutoModel from the transformers library as in:
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, AutoModel
from PIL import Image
import faiss
import numpy as np
import os

#load the model and processor
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained('facebook/dinov2-small')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('facebook/dinov2-small').to(device)

#Populate the images variable with all the images in the dataset folder
images = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./dataset'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('jpg'):
            images.append(root  + '/'+ file)

I get the error: ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes. Where is the problem? Thank you in advance
